# Plain text template using @import omits blank line in imported template

Tags: laravel-blade

Laravel 8.x (due to our platform, I can't upgrade easily).
Using helper class, from: https://github.com/PhiloNL/Laravel-Blade/blob/master/src/Blade.php

I'm very new to Laravel and Blade and am using it to create email bodies, both HTML and plain text.  I find that a header template that ends with a blank line, that blank line is not included in the output if I `@include` it at the start of another template.  This new line is important for the plain text email body.

For example:
`header.blade.php` (note the blank line, I've numbered the lines so they appear correctly here on SO)

```
1 Our Amazing Store dot Com
2
```

`email_body.blade.php`

```
1 @import ('header')
2 Dear customer,
3 Have a great day
```

The result of rendering the `email_body` template has the lines one after another, with no blank line:

```
1 Our Amazing Store dot Com
2 Dear customer,
3 Have a great day
```

To fix this, I seem to have to put the blank line in the `email_body` template, i.e.:

```
1 @import ('header')
2 
3 Dear customer,
4 Have a great day
```

I then get the desired output:

```
1 Our Amazing Store dot Com
2 
3 Dear customer,
4 Have a great day
```

Is this normal behaviour?  How can I make Blade honour the blank line at the end of `header.blade.php`?  I'm aware it's compiled by Blade and executed to produce the output, so I hope there is some statement I can put in the template to cause a blank line to be output.

I experimented with a comment to force a blank line.  On its own it doesn't help, but weirdly a comment followed by a blank line does work in the header:

```
1 Our Amazing Store dot Com
2 {{-- blank line --}}
3
```

But then I find that the footer does not work using the same approach.

```
1
2 {{-- blank line --}}
3 Footer text goes here
```

Results in the blank line being removed, so the body gets put directly next to the footer text that it's supposed to be separated from:

```
1 Our Amazing Store dot Com
2 
3 Dear customer,
4 Have a great day
5 Footer text goes here
```

All rather annoying :) I will work around with the blank lines being in the body template as mentioned above but it's not optimal as that will have to be done across all our body templates.

Comment: why not simply add <br> tag in your blade file where you need it?

Comment: @RaviSigdel because this is a plain text email body I'm generating :)  I'm not using the normal Laravel view system to output HTML to the browser, I'm using Blade templates to generate strings to use with PHPMailer to send an email.

Comment: then your email content type should be Content-Type: text/plain and use '\n'. or using character code "%0A" , This will give you a new line in plain text